# Tabbed Dialog Box using Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtgui, qdialog, qtabwidget

I'm new to Qt and having a problem with the TabbedDialog box designed using the Qt Designer.
I have a Dialog dlg on which i have placed a tabWidget MyTabWidget containing two tabs Tab1 and Tab2. I want to make separate cpp files for each tab and define the functions in their respective files. the problem i'm having is how to access the UI widgets of the dialog dlg in these respective files.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a tab pointer to your function you want to use. Something like:

```
void Class1::yourFunction1(QWidget *tab1);
void Class2::yourFunction2(QWidget *tab2);
```

You can access these widget tabs like:

```
ui->tab
```

if it was created in QtDesigner.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to be taken here which is well-explained in the [following documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).

1) Include `#include "ui_foo.h"`

This is necessary to access the UI elements in your code. This is the file that is available through the QtDesigner and ui compiler, aka. uic process.

2) Either inherit Ui::Foo or have an object with composition with it within your class. It would be something like:

```
class Foo : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Foo(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::Foo ui;
};
```

or

```
class Foo : public QWidget, private Ui::Foo
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Foo(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

3) Then you can use this instance to access the widgets (something like ui->foo) created by the QtDesigner application.

```
bool Foo::doStuff()
{
    ui->foo()->doStuff();
}
```

You probably do not wish to have two separate source files and classes as you wrote, but if you wish, the above steps could be applied for both.

That being said, I think it is better if you go through the aforementioned documentation because it is lot more detailed about the several approaches, and how to access the UI components in your source code generated by QtDesigner.